# AddressSanitizer errors when testing the performance of singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack-overflow, singly-linked-list, address-sanitizer

I am working on a creating a singly linked list. To create that I have wrote structures such as `struct node` and operation like `list_free_node`. Now this is my first time using `malloc` and `pointers`, and I get a few errors (I think related to those two mentioned concepts) that I have never seen before.

The code that I wrote seems to work when I test it myself, I [uploaded](https://onlinegdb.com/BkLIgJPHN) it for testing purposes, it can be compiled and ran online in browser.

However, when I use `make check`, it gets checked automatically by [check_list.c](https://pastebin.com/VtrLnAvG). When that happens I get errors that I have never seen before.

[image: Errors about Deadlysignal].

I searched for those errors and found that it has something to do with a stack overflow. I think the mistake could be that I use a pointer that does not exist or something. However, when I run my code manually it seems to work just fine. I do not understand how this happens.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is probly caused by how you build your app. Please post some details (which compiler version, which flags you use, etc.).

Comment: Don't post images of error messages. Post the error messages as text.

Comment: Will do in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least these errors:

- in `list_add_front()`

  ```
              if (l -> head == NULL) {
                      l -> head = n;
                      return 0;
  ```

  Here you forgot that `n->next` hasn't been initialized; something equivalent to `n->next = NULL` is missing. Of course you could merge the similar `if` and `else` bodies and write solely

  ```
              n -> next = l -> head;
              l -> head = n;
              return 0;
  ```
- in `list_add_back()`

  Here also you forgot that `n->next` hasn't been initialized and `n->next = NULL` is missing.

  Alternatively you could set `n->next = NULL` in `list_new_node()`.
- in `list_cleanup()`

  ```
              currentnode = nextnode;
              list_free_node(currentnode);
              nextnode = list_next(nextnode);
  ```

  We must not use the node contents after the node was freed, thus we must not call `list_next()` (which needs the node's `->next` pointer) after `list_free_node()`. Just swap those last two lines.

Comment: and `list_new_node()` needed `n -> next = NULL;` too. Thanks alot. Everything works now.